# positron / electron annihilation - where is the invariant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, pair-production

Electron and a positron are headed towards each other with same kinetic energies - observed from *center of mass* (COM) system. After the colission two photons are emitted and are headed in opposite directions with the same momentum. hat are photon wavelengths?

In almost every pair production problem we have to use Lorentz invariant $E^2={E_0}^2+(pc)^2$, but I saw in a book that the problem is solved this way:

$$
E_{before}=E_{after}\\
E_{e^+}+ E_{e^-}=2E_\gamma\\
E_{0e^+} + E_{0e^-} + E_{ke^+} + E_{ke^-} = 2 p_\gamma c\\
2 E_{0e^+} + 2E_{ke^+} = 2 \tfrac{h c}{\lambda}\\
\lambda = \frac{hc}{E_{0e^+} + E_{ke^-}}
$$

But is this correct? **Because we never used the Lorentz invariant** i am wondering how this could be solved using the invariant... Can anyone show me how to use the invariant to solve this problem?

Comment: Er...the only Lorentz invariant quantity in the above the mass (i.e. $E_0$ in your notation) of the particles. The total energy of the particle is emphatically *not* invariant under boosts.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand. Is it different fi I say the Lorentz invariance is: $E^2={E_0}^2+(pc)^2$ or if I say: ${E_0}^2 =E^2-(pc)^2$? It is the same equation. Is above example solved correctly?

Comment: Well, perhaps I have misunderstood, but a quantity is called *"a Lorentz invariant"* or *"a Lorentz scalar"* if that quantity doesn't change under a boost. Masses and intervals are examples of invariants as are any other quantities that can be written as the inner product of two four-vectors. This is different from energy being conserved in a interaction (which is true in all frames as well, but the value of the energy differs from frame to frame). I don't quite understand what you are being asked to do, as the solution you exhibit is (up to the missing + in the last line) what I would do.

Comment: Thank you. So as long as I stay in the same coordinate system there is no need to use the equation $E^2={E_0}^2+(pc)^2$. But I have allso been dealing with systems where we used this equation within the same coordinate system to connect the momentum $p$ and energies - in this case it comes quite handy. Is my thinking ok now?

Comment: It occurs to me that the invariance of the mass of the pair is an alternative to using symmetry as a way of establishing that the photons must be back-to-back in the CoM frame. If that is the intent of the question it seems very unclear to me.

Comment: You use the fact that the invariant mass of the photon is zero, when you write that $E_\gamma = p_\gamma c$. I advice you to stop separate the (electron) energy between a mass energy and a kinetic energy. This is totally unnecessary, obscur, and complicated. You may write $E_{e+}=\sqrt{\vec p_{e+}^2 + m_{e+}^2}$, but that's all. And stop use the notation $E_{0x}$ to indicate a mass, use the standard notation $m_x$.